# CSS Non-typical Clear float bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, debugging

I need a new set of eyes on this... I have an issue where the sliding panel on this page (using Nihal Doherty's [Coda Slider 2.0](http://www.ndoherty.biz/demos/coda-slider/2.0/)) is starting off collapsed in a strange way... only about 40% of the time.

Hit REFRESH multiple times to see the bug if you don't see it at first.

I've tried defining a height on the parent in order to prevent the unusual collapsing but even that doesn't work.  There's something I'm missing... Help?!

The site in dev:

http://bellyqueen.com/cms/

Comment: It only happens to me on an unprimed cache, suggesting that you're trying to read the dimensions of an image before it's loaded. Set dimensions on the image's container `<div>` and that should fix it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I see what you mean about the unprimed cache but I was able to duplicate it even with a primed cache. Setting a height on the container `<div>` prevents the page from shortening but leaves a large black space (the image is still illogically pushed up out of view).

Comment: Getting a 404 on your ajax-loader GIF. This isn't the problem you're facing, but it WILL be a problem in Chrome (script won't execute) so you should resolve it, too. Or hey, you never know... it might even be the problem, causing timing issues as the 404 is returned. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @GregPettit - the image is called in the same area - was hopeful maybe it was related, but alas, no dice :( ... it's fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#home_slider` is being in-line styled to `height: 19px` for some reason (probably within the plugin itself). This height changes dynamically to `467px` when it slides for the first time.

I would try setting `autoHeight` in your [plugin settings](http://www.ndoherty.biz/forums/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=2) to `false` and then styling the height in your CSS to `467px`.

Comment: BOOM!  Not sure why, but rather than mess with it I was able to turn the configuration to `autoHeight: off` thereby fixing it.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Edited probably about the same time you posted that comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

The parent height doesn't matter. The height is on the #home_slider, and starts out at 19px. Pretty sure its related to the image not being loaded by the time the widget is initialized. Want to share the JS code that's loading it?

Comment: Thanks @Bob!  @Josh got it already, sorry about that.  See my comment on his answer...